# Cuda eclipse and time.h, Symbol 'CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID' could not be resolved although program runs

Tags: eclipse, cuda, header-files, nsight

I admit, this is not really a problem, but more an annoying thing: basically in the Eclipse editor, installed by the Cuda toolkit, I am using this function:

```
/* Get current value of clock CLOCK_ID and store it in TP.  */
extern int clock_gettime (clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp) __THROW;
```

as the following:

```
clock_gettime((clockid_t)CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
```

The "problem" is that `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is not resolved, and then the whole project appears as containing some error, but if I compile and run, no problem at all

I have included this

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
```

I included also the rt library. How do I make the error go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your includes to your project's preferences:

Right click on your project, choose *General/Paths and Symbols*. There, you can add your custom include directories that will be browsed by Nsight for symbols.

Comment: Thanks! I used a printf to discover the int value and then I added to the Symbols list. And it worked like a charm. Thnaks :)